# Automobile accident data in India

Tags: data-request, traffic, india

I want accident data in India along with gender of the driver. Actually I want to find out that whether the following statement is true or not: 'Are Men Better Drivers Than Women?'.

Comment: [Not true](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2004/may/13/thisweekssciencequestions), but you may ask at Skeptics.SE?

Comment: I just want to show whether its valid or not.. but with proof of data... that's i posted it here.. :/

Comment: Here in the states, you would need to have a government agency provide you with the data. If they will not provide it, you could talk to a local auto insurance agency to get information from them.

Comment: @DanielMiller okay thanks. But in India its not easy. So many question..etc etc..